# Неопределенный оператор delete

Tags: c++, cmake, arduino, avr

Код

```
class Test {};

void setup() {
    Test * t = new Test();
    delete t;
}
```

Компилирую скетч для Ардуино на cmake + avr. На строчке с delete Получаю ошибку

> undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'

это что такое? Зачем компилятор (а вернее линковщик) требует переопределения оператора `delete` да еще и с такими параметрами?

Содержимое CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ArduinoToolchain.cmake)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(PROJECT_NAME Controller)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_BOARD uno)
# set(ARDUINO_CPU)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
file(GLOB SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
file(GLOB HDR_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS ${SRC_FILES})
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HDRS ${HDR_FILES})

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_PORT COM4)

generate_arduino_firmware(${PROJECT_NAME}
        SRCS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS}
        HDRS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HDRS}
        )

print_board_list()
print_programmer_list()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112130/discussion-on-question-by-anton-shchyrov---delete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C++14 появился перегруженный оператор `delete`

```
void operator delete  ( void* ptr, std::size_t sz ) noexcept;
```

который удаляет память указанного размера. В ардуиновской библиотеке определены только такие варианты

```
void * operator new(size_t size);
void * operator new[](size_t size);
void * operator new(size_t size, void * ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete(void * ptr);
void operator delete[](void * ptr);
```

Я понизил в `CMakeLists.txt` версию с++ до 11

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

и все стало компилироваться

Answer (score 2):

Это происходит, так как `avr-g++` не поддерживает `libstdc++`

Из [avr-libc FAQ](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus)

> **Can I use C++ on the AVR?**
>
> Basically yes, C++ is supported (assuming
> your compiler has been configured and compiled to support it, of
> course). Source files ending in .cc, .cpp or .C will automatically
> cause the compiler frontend to invoke the C++ compiler. Alternatively,
> the C++ compiler could be explicitly called by the name avr-c++.
>
> However, there's currently **no support for libstdc++**, the standard
> support library needed for a complete C++ implementation. This imposes
> a number of restrictions on the C++ programs that can be compiled.
> Among them are:
>
> - Obviously, none of the C++ related standard functions, classes, and
>   template classes are available.
> - **The operators new and delete are not implemented**, attempting to use them will cause the linker to complain
>   about undefined external references. (This could perhaps be fixed.)
> - Some of the supplied include files are not C++ safe, i. e. they need
>   to be wrapped into `extern "C" { . . . }` (This could certainly be
>   fixed, too.)
> - Exceptions are not supported. Since exceptions are
>   enabled by default in the C++ frontend, they explicitly need to be
>   turned off using -fno-exceptions in the compiler options. Failing
>   this, the linker will complain about an undefined external reference
>   to `__gxx_personality_sj0`. Constructors and destructors are supported
>   though, including global ones.
>
> When programming C++ in space- and runtime-sensitive environments like
> microcontrollers, extra care should be taken to avoid unwanted side
> effects of the C++ calling conventions like implied copy constructors
> that could be called upon function invocation etc. These things could
> easily add up into a considerable amount of time and program memory
> wasted. Thus, casual inspection of the generated assembler code (using
> the -S compiler option) seems to be warranted.

Библиотека `arduino` содержит реализацию `new/delete`(файлы `new.cpp` и `new.h`), но используемый Вами скрипт `ArduinoToolchain.cmake` не подключает их при сборке библиотеки `arduino core`

Вы можете попробовать другую реализацию `Arduino Toolchain` для `cmake`

Например, https://github.com/a9183756-gh/Arduino-CMake-Toolchain

Пример файл проекта для `cmake`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(test_uno CXX)

add_executable(test_uno main.cpp)

target_link_arduino_libraries(test_uno PRIVATE core)

target_enable_arduino_upload(test_uno)
```

Параметры `cmake`:

```sh
cmake \
   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/Arduino-toolchain.cmake \
   -DARDUINO_BOARD="avr.uno" \
   /path/to/sources.dir
```

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

class Test {};

void setup() {
    Test * t = new Test();
    delete t;
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: Все подключалось. Не хватало конкретного перегруженного оператора. Я откатился до С++11 и все заработало